# Bless Error For saving space

Tags: user-space

Getting a Bless error when I try to modify a file.
"There is not enough space on the device to save yfxmsecc.bless".
Got a ton of free space.
Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Add the output of `df -h` and `df -i` in your question, please.

Comment: Out of inodes ?

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in Bless. See the bug report on Launchpad: [Bless cannot save edited files](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bless/+bug/876021) .
In the Debian bugtracker is a [nice workaround](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=767216#10): Use the "Save as" option. Save to a dummy file instead ("Save As") and it just
works.

Comment: Using "Save as" can become cumbersome for repeated edits, but setting the temp directory, as suggested in the linked bug report, solved the problem cleanly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the bug report suggestion (https://askubuntu.com/a/1006718/46437) and edited the temporary directory in preferences to an HD with a lot of space and it stopped complaining.

But i did not had patience to try merely to /tmp/, so it may work for you.

Remember to thx @AlbertoM too :)